# cloudflare for joomla website and how to make it more optimized

Tags: joomla, optimization, cloudflare

In our office somebody told to use cloudflare for better website browsing at client end.!!

I've put our company's website on cloudflare, now.. what other changes should i make to make my website faster accessible by client end. The developer before me made our company's website in Joomla.. I'm not a good developer in Joomla either. Is joomla itself a faster kind of stuff producer???

And what other stuff should i follow to make my joomla website faster?